# How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, memorystream

If I am given a `MemoryStream` that I know has been populated with a `String`, how do I get a `String` back out?

Comment: Never quite sure if reader.close is always required. I have had issues in the past so as a rule I always do just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

This sample shows how to read and write a string to a MemoryStream.

---

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    ' We don't need to dispose any of the MemoryStream 
    ' because it is a managed object. However, just for 
    ' good practice, we'll close the MemoryStream.
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
      Dim sw As New StreamWriter(ms)
      sw.WriteLine("Hello World")
      ' The string is currently stored in the 
      ' StreamWriters buffer. Flushing the stream will 
      ' force the string into the MemoryStream.
      sw.Flush()
      ' If we dispose the StreamWriter now, it will close 
      ' the BaseStream (which is our MemoryStream) which 
      ' will prevent us from reading from our MemoryStream
      'sw.Dispose()

      ' The StreamReader will read from the current 
      ' position of the MemoryStream which is currently 
      ' set at the end of the string we just wrote to it. 
      ' We need to set the position to 0 in order to read 
      ' from the beginning.
      ms.Position = 0
      Dim sr As New StreamReader(ms)
      Dim myStr = sr.ReadToEnd()
      Console.WriteLine(myStr)

      ' We can dispose our StreamWriter and StreamReader 
      ' now, though this isn't necessary (they don't hold 
      ' any resources open on their own).
      sw.Dispose()
      sr.Dispose()
    End Using

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.")
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Isn't it going to dispose of the StreamWriter when the function goes out of scope anyway?

Comment: Dispose is not called when a variable goes out of scope. Finalize will be called when the GC gets around to it, but Dispose is something that must be called before the variable goes out of scope. I don't call it above because I know the implementation of StreamWriter and StreamReader don't require Dispose to be called, it just passes the call to the underlying stream. However, a legitimate argument can be made for calling Dipose for anything that implements IDisposable since you can't guarantee a future release won't require it to be disposed.

Comment: @MichaelEakins Why should the answer even be in C#, when the question is tagged as VB.Net?

Comment: I'm glad I learned about the "helpers" passing the dispose call to their underlying streams, but this seems like a bad design decision.

Comment: This decision was mitigated later on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Answer (score 393):

You can also use

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

I don't *think* this is less efficient, but I couldn't swear to it.  It also lets you choose a different encoding, whereas using a StreamReader you'd have to specify that as a parameter.

Comment: Encoding is in the System.Text namespace

Comment: I was looking for the PowerShell equivalent of this and had to use this. ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII).GetString(ms.ToArray())

Comment: This solution is useful as it can be used after the MemoryStream has been closed.

Comment: FWIW, I found this didn't work with very large strings, I was getting `OutOfMemoryException`s.  Using a `StreamReader` instead solved the problem.

Comment: Since this can be a pitfall: It's not aware of byte order mark and might include a Hex `00` in the beginning of the string.`00 3C 3F` -> `.<?` in Hex Editor but in VS or Notepad++: `<?`. So you can't see the difference even if you compare the strings by eye, only a comparison tool or Hex editor will show the difference. If you still use it, think about String.TrimStart. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: if your content is UTF8 you also can `System.Text.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())`

Comment: @Jirapong, to use **UTF8** is a great comment in year 2020, but on .NET Framework 4.x your code doesn't work. Instead it's successful with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()`. Maybe your code is wrong or targeting .NET core? Nevertheless: Thanks!

Comment: In PowerShell try this fancy punctuation `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($memoryStreamObject.ToArray())`

Answer (score 105):

Using a StreamReader to convert the MemoryStream to a String.

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ReadAll(ByVal memStream As MemoryStream) As String
    ' Reset the stream otherwise you will just get an empty string.
    ' Remember the position so we can restore it later.
    Dim pos = memStream.Position
    memStream.Position = 0

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(memStream)
    Dim str = reader.ReadToEnd()

    ' Reset the position so that subsequent writes are correct.
    memStream.Position = pos

    Return str
End Function
```

Comment: Setting the Position to 0 limits the reuse ability of the method -- it is best to let the caller manage this.  What if the stream contains data prior to the string, that the caller knows how to handle?

Comment: The using statement will ensure that your StreamReader gets disposed, but the documentation says that StreamReader closes the underlying stream when it gets disposed. Therefore, your method closes the MemoryStream it gets passed, which is conceptually uncool for callers even if I doubt MemoryStream.Dispose does much.

Comment: You are correct. It is typically a bad idea to use the Dispose method on the stream helper classes, especially if the stream is passed into a method as a parameter. I'll update this answer. I also have a more complete answer below.

Comment: If you decompile those classes, you'll see that the dispose method simply calls Dispose() on any streams that are not null in the instance (TextWriter, MemoryStream, etc)

Answer (score 47):

use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), then you can use the [ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method that returns a string.

Comment: I just want to mention, that the `Basestream` should has set its Position to 0. Like `memoryStream.Position = 0;`.

Answer (score 40):

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyTest1 - MyTest2");
MemoryStream streamItem = new MemoryStream(array);

// convert to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamItem);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 27):

Previous solutions wouldn't work in cases where encoding is involved. Here is - kind of a "real life" - example how to do this properly...

```cs
using(var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
  var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<ExportData>),  new[]{typeof(ExportData)}, Int32.MaxValue, true, null, false);               
  serializer.WriteObject(stream, model);  


  var jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString((stream.ToArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 23):

In this case, if you really want to use `ReadToEnd` method in `MemoryStream` in an easy way, you can use this Extension Method to achieve this:

```cs
public static class SetExtensions
{
    public static string ReadToEnd(this MemoryStream BASE)
    {
        BASE.Position = 0;
        StreamReader R = new StreamReader(BASE);
        return R.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And you can use this method in this way:

```cs
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    //for example i want to serialize an object into MemoryStream
    //I want to use XmlSeralizer
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(_yourVariable.GetType());
    xs.Serialize(m, _yourVariable);

    //the easy way to use ReadToEnd method in MemoryStream
    MessageBox.Show(m.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Setting `Position = 0` helped me.

Answer (score 11):

This sample shows how to read a string from a MemoryStream, in which I've used a serialization (using DataContractJsonSerializer), pass the string from some server to client, and then, how to recover the MemoryStream from the string passed as parameter, then, deserialize the MemoryStream.

I've used parts of different posts to perform this sample.

Hope that this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;

namespace JsonSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone { Type = PhoneTypes.Home, Number = "28736127" },
                new Phone { Type = PhoneTypes.Movil, Number = "842736487" }
            };
            var p = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person 1", BirthDate = DateTime.Now, Phones = phones };

            Console.WriteLine("New object 'Person' in the server side:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Birthday: {2}.", p.Id, p.Name, p.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Phone: {0} {1}", p.Phones[0].Type.ToString(), p.Phones[0].Number));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Phone: {0} {1}", p.Phones[1].Type.ToString(), p.Phones[1].Number));

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));

            ser.WriteObject(stream1, p);

            stream1.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
            Console.Write("JSON form of Person object: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var f = GetStringFromMemoryStream(stream1);

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Passing string parameter from server to client...");

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var g = GetMemoryStreamFromString(f);
            g.Position = 0;
            var ser2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
            var p2 = (Person)ser2.ReadObject(g);

            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("New object 'Person' arrived to the client:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Birthday: {2}.", p2.Id, p2.Name, p2.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Phone: {0} {1}", p2.Phones[0].Type.ToString(), p2.Phones[0].Number));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Phone: {0} {1}", p2.Phones[1].Type.ToString(), p2.Phones[1].Number));

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static MemoryStream GetMemoryStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            sw.Write(s);
            sw.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        private static string GetStringFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class Phone
    {
        [DataMember]
        public PhoneTypes Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    internal enum PhoneTypes
    {
        Home = 1,
        Movil = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not make a nice extension method on the MemoryStream type?

```
public static class MemoryStreamExtensions
{

    static object streamLock = new object();

    public static void WriteLine(this MemoryStream stream, string text, bool flush)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text + Environment.NewLine);
        lock (streamLock)
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (flush)
            {
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void WriteLine(this MemoryStream stream, string formatString, bool flush, params string[] strings)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(formatString, strings) + Environment.NewLine);
        lock (streamLock)
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (flush)
            {
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void WriteToConsole(this MemoryStream stream)
    {
        lock (streamLock)
        {
            long temporary = stream.Position;
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 0x1000, true))
            {
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
            stream.Position = temporary;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, be careful when using these methods in conjunction with the standard ones. :) ...you'll need to use that handy streamLock if you do, for concurrency.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly modified version of Brian's answer allows optional management of read start, This seems to be the easiest method.  probably not the most efficient, but easy to understand and use.

```
Public Function ReadAll(ByVal memStream As MemoryStream, Optional ByVal startPos As Integer = 0) As String
    ' reset the stream or we'll get an empty string returned
    ' remember the position so we can restore it later
    Dim Pos = memStream.Position
    memStream.Position = startPos

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(memStream)
    Dim str = reader.ReadToEnd()

    ' reset the position so that subsequent writes are correct
    memStream.Position = Pos

    Return str
End Function
```

Comment: it really adds nothing new to Brian answer

Answer (score 1):

I need to integrate with a class that need a Stream to Write on it:

```
XmlSchema schema;
// ... Use "schema" ...

var ret = "";

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    schema.Write(ms);
    ret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
//here you can use "ret"
// 6 Lines of code
```

I create a simple class that can help to reduce lines of code for multiples use:

```
public static class MemoryStreamStringWrapper
{
    public static string Write(Action<MemoryStream> action)
    {
        var ret = "";
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            action(ms);
            ret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

then you can replace the sample with a single line of code

```
var ret = MemoryStreamStringWrapper.Write(schema.Write);
```

Answer (score -1):

Only use method Convert.ToBase64String

```
Convert.ToBase64String(inputStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: Why would you want to use ToBase64String if content is just clear text?

Answer (score -1):

// Create a StreamReader object to read from MemoryStream object.

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);

// Read MemoryStream object to a string.

memoryStreamValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Close StreamReader obj.

reader.Close();

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers, I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)