# Writing String to Stream and reading it back does not work

Tags: c#, stream

I want to write a String to a Stream (a MemoryStream in this case) and read the bytes one by one.

```
stringAsStream = new MemoryStream();
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
String message = "Message";

stringAsStream.Write(uniEncoding.GetBytes(message), 0, message.Length);

Console.WriteLine("This:\t\t" + (char)uniEncoding.GetBytes(message)[0]);
Console.WriteLine("Differs from:\t" + (char)stringAsStream.ReadByte());
```

The (undesired) result I get is:

```
This:         M
Differs from: ?
```

It *looks* like it's not being read correctly, as the first char of "Message" is 'M', which works when getting the bytes from the UnicodeEncoding instance but not when reading them back from the stream.

What am I doing wrong?

---

The bigger picture: I have an algorithm which will work on the bytes of a Stream, I'd like to be as general as possible and work with any Stream. I'd like to convert an ASCII-String into a MemoryStream, or maybe use another method to be able to work on the String as a Stream. The algorithm in question will work on the bytes of the Stream.

Comment: Do you want to read the bytes or the characters one by one from the stream? Note that byte != char as your encoding is Unicode.

Comment: Yes I do. And byte will be char as I will be reading ASCII-documents. Would it be better to use something other than uniEncoding in my case?

Comment: I added a bigger picture as requested.

Comment: I updated my answer with a code sample that might work a little better for you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! And sorry for not including the bigger picture from the beginning, since it was necessary in this case. All answers provided value, so you all got an up vote from me at least. :)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

After you write to the `MemoryStream` and before you read it back, you need to `Seek` back to the beginning of the `MemoryStream` so you're not reading from the end.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your update, I think there's a more reliable way to build the stream:

```
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
String message = "Message";

// You might not want to use the outer using statement that I have
// I wasn't sure how long you would need the MemoryStream object    
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, uniEncoding);
    try
    {
        sw.Write(message);
        sw.Flush();//otherwise you are risking empty stream
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Test and work with the stream here. 
        // If you need to start back at the beginning, be sure to Seek again.
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code uses a StreamWriter to write the entire string (with proper encoding) out to the `MemoryStream`. This takes the hassle out of ensuring the entire byte array for the string is written.

**Update:** I stepped into issue with empty stream several time. It's enough to call **Flush** right after you've finished writing.

Comment: That code will fail at `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`, because putting a using on StreamWriter will close its stream, which in this case is the MemoryStream. Then when you try to seek, it will give you a `Cannot access a closed Stream` exception.

Comment: You can use this approach if you wrap the stream in a class which overrides the disposal of the underlying stream. [This response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465824/is-it-okay-to-not-close-streamreader-streamwriter-to-keep-the-underlying-stream-o/4466519#4466519) to a related question points to [an implementation](http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/IO/NonClosingStream.cs).

Comment: As noted, this code doesn't compile.  The answer from Joel Purra is a one-liner and works much better.

Answer (score 46):

Try this "one-liner" from [Delta's Blog](http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/), [String To MemoryStream (C#)](http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/string-to-memorystream-c/).

```
MemoryStream stringInMemoryStream =
   new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("Your string here"));
```

The string will be loaded into the [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), and you can read from it. See [Encoding.GetBytes(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h.aspx), which has also been [implemented for a few other encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8).

Comment: And to get the data back, [`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234262/).

Comment: I strongly urge anyone using this example to use Encoding.UTF8 over ASCII – or any other wider-scoped encoding. Chances are good any text written by non-{american, english, …} people will render badly in ASCII.

Answer (score 21):

You're using `message.Length` which returns the number of *characters* in the string, but you should be using the nubmer of *bytes* to read. You should use something like:

```
byte[] messageBytes = uniEncoding.GetBytes(message);
stringAsStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
```

You're then reading a single *byte* and expecting to get a character from it just by casting to `char`. `UnicodeEncoding` will use two bytes per character.

As Justin says you're *also* not seeking back to the beginning of the stream.

Basically I'm afraid pretty much everything is wrong here. Please give us the bigger picture and we can help you work out what you should *really* be doing. Using a `StreamWriter` to write and then a `StreamReader` to read is quite possibly what you want, but we can't really tell from just the brief bit of code you've shown.

Comment: After you write to a MemoryStream, aren't you required to Seek back to the beginning to begin reading again?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, that's another problem :)

Comment: I've added a bigger picture as requested. Maybe it's easier to understand what I want to do now.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be a lot more productive to use a `TextWriter`, in this case a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to write to the MemoryStream. After that, as other have said, you need to "rewind" the MemoryStream using something like `stringAsStream.Position = 0L;`.

```
stringAsStream = new MemoryStream();

// create stream writer with UTF-16 (Unicode) encoding to write to the memory stream
using(StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(stringAsStream, UnicodeEncoding.Unicode))
{
  sWriter.Write("Lorem ipsum.");
}
stringAsStream.Position = 0L; // rewind
```

Note that:

> StreamWriter defaults to using an instance of UTF8Encoding  unless specified otherwise. This instance of UTF8Encoding  is constructed without a byte order mark (BOM)

Also, you don't have to create a `new UnicodeEncoding()` usually, since there's already one as a static member of the class for you to use in convenient utf-8, utf-16, and utf-32 flavors.

And then, finally (as others have said) you're trying to convert the `byte`s directly to `char`s, which they are not. If I had a memory stream and knew it was a string, I'd use a `TextReader` to get the string back from the bytes. It seems "dangerous" to me to mess around with the raw bytes.

Comment: My main object is to work with Streams. As I will be working on the bytes of ASCII-text and binary files.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, I guess you'll have to mess with them bytes. ;)

Comment: One thing on the rewind part, I get `Cannot access a closed Stream.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the stream to the beginning:

```
stringAsStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Console.WriteLine("Differs from:\t" + (char)stringAsStream.ReadByte());
```

This can also be done by setting the `Position` property to 0:

```
stringAsStream.Position = 0
```