# Generic read/write to byte array

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to be able to put generic variables to byte array (to save it to database with EF)

I tried this way:

```
public byte[] SerializedParams { get; set; } // property for EF

...

public void Write(params object[] args)
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, args);

        SerializedParams = ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public T Read<T>()
{
    var byteSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(SerializedParams, 0, SerializedParams.Length);
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var x = bf.Deserialize(ms); // error here
        return (T)x;
    }
}
```

var x = bf.Deserialize(ms); this line causes an error.
after calling:

```
qr.Write(5,7,9);
var i1 = qr.Read<int>(); // error here
var i2 = qr.Read<int>();
var i3 = qr.Read<int>();
```

> "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."

What's wrong with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing String to Stream and reading it back does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629612/writing-string-to-stream-and-reading-it-back-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the position property of the memorystream to 0:

```
public T Read<T>()
{
    var byteSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(SerializedParams, 0, SerializedParams.Length);
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        ms.Position = 0; // this line should do the trick
        var x = bf.Deserialize(ms); 
        return (T)x;
    }
}
```