# C# GZipStream to String

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am in need of a way to write a GZipStream to a string.

I am using:

```
GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress)
```

I have tried several methods, but can't figure it out.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream)

Comment: When I use :
var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
the string comes back empty. Might I be missing something on converting a GZipStream to a MemoryStream?

Comment: if your inFile is always a text file then solution/link suggested by @Steven will work. It the formats are different then you can only have a bade64 representation of the data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a decompressing [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx), so you need to read data from it. The easiest way is to wrap the `GZipStream` with a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) which has a [`ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method returning a string.

Something like:

```
string res;
using (var decompress = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(decompress)) {
  res = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(`using` statements ensure that `inFile` is closed and any other resources are freed.)

*NB* this does assume that `inFile` contains text encoded UTF-8 or UTF-16. Binary content or other text encoding could cause problems (you can override the encoding with a different `StreamReader` constructor).