# Trying To Gzip and Unzip but getting different content

Tags: c#, gzip

I have the following functions to gzip and unzip text content, however the uncompressed output is not complete, missing approx the last 10th of the file (long html file). What am I doing wrong?

```
private byte[] GZipString(string input)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gz = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        gz.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return mso.ToArray();
    }
}

private string UnzipFile(string filename)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gz = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        gz.CopyTo(mso);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know the language, but guessing that `GZipStream` is buffering, so you have to grab `mso.ToArray()` after closing the compressor (outside the `using` block).

Comment: Decompress into a `StreamReader`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# GZipStream to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469153/c-sharp-gzipstream-to-string)

Comment: @Phill regarding the claim of a dupe, this regards both compression and decompression. that question concerns only decompressing.

Comment: @Phill even decompressing to a `streamreader` still cuts short the content.

Comment: Ah I think your compression you need to set the seek position to 0 before returning.

Comment: When trying to uncompress with 7zip, I get the error "unexpected end of data", so the compression is certainly iffy. And really, 2 close votes? It's nothing like the so-called "Duplicate"

Comment: @user508633 put your answer back!

Comment: @user3791372 Er, "a moderator has deleted this post, it cannot be undeleted" :(. I do think the essence of my answer was correct, but sorry, I can't revert. And yes, I do in fact know C# is a language - I'm just much less familiar with C# itself than I am with dealing with streams in Java, but I expect they work similarly.

Comment: @Phill Can you double check here whether my answer was actually wrong? Given that the output file was corrupted as seen from 7z, it does seem like the root cause was in compression, not decompression.

Comment: @user508633 too many wannabe point-hungry mods here have an itchy trigger finger and will mark any question as a duplicate and "clean up" for the points. I asked the very same question again (thus polluting SO because of whichever mod is responsible for marking this a dupe) and got the answer you put with the addition of an explanation. SO is going downhill, get used to it :(