# Decompress ZIP Stream

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

For some reason I cannot find any examples for doing so with `DotNetZip`.

I receive a `Gziped` content from my `WebAPI`.

All I want to do is to read that memory stream from the response and unzip the content(text) into a string.

My compression working fine, I just can't figure out the decompress:

```
public static byte[] CompressData(byte[] str)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (
            var compressor = new Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream(
            output, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress,
            Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed))
        {
            compressor.Write(str, 0, str.Length);
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469153/c-sharp-gzipstream-to-string this answer might help you :)

Comment: What's wrong with saving the zip file in a tmp directory and then decompressing it afterwards ?

Comment: read this https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Comment: @Fourat sounds redundant

Comment: @omriman12 but safe and easy

Comment: @Fourat  take a look at my answer

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows how the program extracts the files from the archive.

```
private void ExtractArchive(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(txtArchiveName.zip))
        {
            // Loop through the archive's files.
            foreach (ZipEntry zip_entry in zip)
            {
                zip_entry.Extract(txtExtractTo);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error extracting archive.\n" +
            ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The simplest way to Extract all the entries from a zipfile looks like this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(NameOfExistingZipFile))
  {
    zip.ExtractAll(args[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the solution. Pretty simple actually, but very poorly documented online.

```
 public static byte[] Decompress(Stream ms)
{
    byte[] outData = null;
    using (MemoryStream msInner = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (DeflateStream defStream = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            defStream.CopyTo(msInner);
            outData = msInner.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return outData;
}
```