# Serializing a memorystream object to string

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, memorystream

Right now I'm using XmlTextWriter to convert a MemoryStream object into string. But I wan't to know whether there is a faster method to serialize a memorystream to string.

I follow the code given here for serialization - http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/system.xml.xmlserialization.asp

**Edited**

**Stream to String**

```
ms.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    SaveInDB(ms);
}
```

**String to Stream**

```
string content = GetFromContentDB();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray); 
byte[] outBuf = ms.GetBuffer(); //error here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
   stream.Position = 0;
   var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
   string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You cant use GetBuffer when you use [MemoryStream(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) constructor.

**MSDN quote:**

> This constructor does not expose the
>   underlying stream. GetBuffer throws
>   UnauthorizedAccessException.

You must use this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y0t45kk.aspx) and set `publiclyVisible = true` in order to use GetBuffer

Comment: I'm afraid this is not giving the write string. After I try to convert the string back to memory stream it is throwing error message "MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed." while doing memorystream.GetBuffer().

Comment: Have updated the code in the post. The original Memory stream is around 95000 bytes. But after I convert the string back to stream I'm getting only 1900 bytes.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but are you sure that the database field is big enough? Does the conversion work if you store it in memory instead of the DB?

Comment: @Matthew I too have the same doubt. I'm investigating on that right now since I'm using a library that does not expose the schema of the database to me.

Comment: Oops. Storing/retrieval of the string is the problem. I'm not able to retrieve the full string from the DB as the max capacity of the column is less. Just did a quick check of the string length before saving it and after retrieving it. Will sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.net  i used this

> Dim TempText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(TempMemoryStream.ToArray())

in C# may apply