# Serializing JSON with DataContractJsonSerializer in C# gives trailing null characters (\0)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, null, datacontractjsonserializer

When serializing a JSON I get trailing null characters which makes my unit test fail. The serializer looks like this:

```
public static string SerializeJSON<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, true))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(jsonWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
        }
    }
```

I have written a unit test for it that looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void SerializeJSON()
    {
        string testJSON = File.ReadAllText(@"Util\\TestCurrency.json");
        Currency currency = StaticExamples.ccy1;
        string json = SerializeUtil.SerializeJSON(currency);
        Assert.AreEqual(testJSON, json);
    }
```

Which compares the serialized currency to the file example, they should be identical. But the test fails saying:

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<{
"code": "USD",
"currencyId": 1,
"name": "Dollar",
"status": "Active"
}>. 
Actual:<{
"code": "USD",
"currencyId": 1,
"name": "Dollar",
"status": "Active"
}\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>.
```

The trailing characters are null characters from what I understand. Any idea of why they appear? It works to Deserialize this JSON again but my test still fails.
This is tha class being serialized:

```
public class Currency
{       
    public int currencyId { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT with answer**
Thanks to @DavidG I changed the way I converted the stream to a string and it works know. This is the generic serializer code for anyone who wants it:

```
public static string SerializeJSON<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, true))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(jsonWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
            }
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this to get your string instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161453/serializing-a-memorystream-object-to-string

Comment: Thanks @DavidG! That worked great! Its the small things... Know why it behaved that way?

Comment: Well you're trying to get the string from `memoryStream.GetBuffer()` which contains a tonne of empty space at the end of the buffer.