# Simple webclient request returning MS.InternalMemoryStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a simple webclient that connects to a webpage and returns the data. The code is as follows:

```
try
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://domain.com/register.php?username=" + txtbUser.Text);
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted +=
        new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        //Process web service result here       
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        //Process web service failure here       
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

The data coming from `e.Result` is `MS.InternalMemoryStream` and not the data coming back from the webpage, the data coming back from the webpage should just be a 0 or 1. Any idea's?

thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.ToString() returns the name of the class - in this case, InternalMemoryStream. You have to READ the stream to get the result. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream) out