# StringStream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, stringstream

I want to be able to build a string from a class that I create that derives from `Stream`. Specifically, I want to be able to write code like this:

```
void Print(Stream stream) {
    // Some code that operates on a Stream.
}

void Main() {
    StringStream stream = new StringStream();
    Print(stream);
    string myString = stream.GetResult();
}
```

Can I create a class called `StringStream` that makes this possible? Or is such a class already available?

**Update:** In my example, the method `Print` is provided in a third-party external DLL. As you can see, the argument that `Print` expects is a `Stream`. After printing to the `Stream`, I want to be able to retrieve its content as a string.

Comment: Have you consider using `StringBuilder` instead?

Comment: What happens if the `Stream` does not represent a `string`? What exactly are you trying to achieve with such a thing?

Comment: Can you please provide us the signature of the external API-method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use tandem of [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) classes:

```
void Main()
{
    string myString;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Print(stream);

        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            myString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

Since your Print() method presumably deals with Text data, could you rewrite it to accept a `TextWriter` parameter?

The library provides a `StringWriter: TextWriter` but not a StringStream.  I suppose you could create one by wrapping a MemoryStream, but is it really necessary?

---

**After the Update:**

```
void Main() 
{
  string myString;  // outside using

  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ())
  {
     Print(stream);
     myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
  }
  ... 

}
```

You may want to change UTF8 to ASCII, depending on the encoding used by Print().

Comment: GetBuffer() returns the whole buffer with a tail of zeros for me. ToArray() works for me instead.

Comment: @Fox32: Be aware that `ToArray()` creates a new array, wheareas `GetBuffer()` returns the internal array.

Comment: This answer works for getting a string out of a stream.  For the inverse (getting a stream out of a string), you can do `var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string"));`

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) to write values to a string.  It provides a stream-like syntax (though does not derive from `Stream`) which works with an underlying `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted since it doesn't solve the poster's question. StringWriter isn't a Stream and therefore cannot be used as one.

Comment: @Neutrino The OP's code didn't *need* to be using a `Stream` - this is a better design choice, in this case.

Comment: I read the OP's statement "method Print in external dll. I need to use Stream" to mean that Print is either external code that cannot be modified, or that other design constraints mandate the use of Stream in it's method signature. In which case refactoring Print's signature does not answer the question as stated, although perhaps the question is just ambiguously worded.

Comment: I came here looking for a string stream, not a string writer

Comment: @Isaac This directly answers the original poster's question.  If you're trying to read from a string as a `Stream`, you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 11):

I see a lot of good answers here, but none that directly address the lack of a StringStream class in C#.  So I have written one of my own...

```
public class StringStream : Stream
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _memory;
    public StringStream(string text)
    {
        _memory = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    }
    public StringStream()
    {
        _memory = new MemoryStream();
    }
    public StringStream(int capacity)
    {
        _memory = new MemoryStream(capacity);
    }
    public override void Flush()
    {
        _memory.Flush();
    }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return  _memory.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _memory.Seek(offset, origin);
    }
    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _memory.SetLength(value);
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _memory.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
    public override bool CanRead => _memory.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => _memory.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => _memory.CanWrite;
    public override long Length =>  _memory.Length;
    public override long Position
    {
        get => _memory.Position;
        set => _memory.Position = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_memory.GetBuffer(), 0, (int) _memory.Length);
    }
    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        return _memory.ReadByte();
    }
    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        _memory.WriteByte(value);
    }
}
```

An example of its use...

```
        string s0 =
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\r\n" +
            "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud\r\n" +
            "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor\r\n" +
            "in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint\r\n" +
            "occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\r\n";
        StringStream ss0 = new StringStream(s0);
        StringStream ss1 = new StringStream();
        int line = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of input stream: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ss0))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ss1))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string s = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Line " + line++ + ": " + s);
                    writer.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of output stream: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(ss1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a MemoryStream from a String and use that in any third-party function that *requires* a stream. In this case, MemoryStream, with the help of UTF8.GetBytes, provides the functionality of Java's StringStream.

### From String examples

```
String content = "stuff";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
{
    Print(stream); //or whatever action you need to perform with the stream
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //If you need to use the same stream again, don't forget to reset it.
    UseAgain(stream);
}
```

### To String example

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string s;
using (var readr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    s = readr.ReadToEnd();
}
//and don't forget to dispose the stream if you created it
```

Comment: I thought I'd post an answer that actually matches the title, since that is what most people come here looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options:

One is to not use streams, but use the TextWriter

```
   void Print(TextWriter writer) 
   {
   }

   void Main() 
  {
    var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    Print(writer);
    string myString = textWriter.ToString();
   }
```

It's likely that `TextWriter` is the appropriate level of abstraction for your `print` function.
Streams are aimed at writing binary data, while TextWriter works at a higher abstraction level, specifically geared towards outputting strings.

If your motivation is that you also want your `Print` function to write to files, you can get a text writer from a filestream as well.

```
void Print(TextWriter writer) 
{
}

void PrintToFile(string filePath) 
{
     using(var textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
     {
         Print(writer);
     }
}
```

If you REALLY want a stream you can look at `MemoryStream`.

Comment: **RE: you can get a text writer from a filestream as well.** Yes, I see that [`StreamWriter` derives from `TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).