# Converting DotNetZip memory stream to string

Tags: c#, streamreader, memorystream, stringstream, dotnetzip

I am trying to read a file within a zip to check if that file has a certain string in it. But I can seem to get the "file" (memory stream) into a string in order to search it.

When I use the following code "stringOfStream" is always blank, what am I doing wrong? The reader always has a length and read byte returns different numbers.

```
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(currentFile.FullName))
        {
            ZipEntry e = zip[this.searchFile.Text];

            using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream())
            {
                e.Extract(reader);
                var stringReader = new StreamReader(reader);
                var stringOfStream = stringReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I would try to set the position of the stream to 0 before calling `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: I believe Florent B. is correct, based on the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887538/how-to-use-dotnetzip-to-extract-xml-file-from-zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you call Extract the position of the stream goes to the end of the file, so you need to reposition again to get the data.

Can you try this please :

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(currentFile.FullName))
 {
            ZipEntry e = zip[this.searchFile.Text];

            using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream())
            {
                e.Extract(reader);
                reader.Position = 0;
                var stringReader = new StreamReader(reader);
                var stringOfStream = stringReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

  }
```

Check if it works or not.

Comment: sometimes solutions are so desperately simple! thanks!!

Comment: does anyone know if ZipFile.Read(currentFile.FullName) locks the file? or can it still be written too?