# How to use Stream to get String

Tags: vb.net

I have a method in a third-party tool that has the following criteria:

```
ExportToXML(fileName As String) 'Saves the content to file in a form of XML document
```

or

```
ExportToXML(stream As System.IO.Stream) 'Saves the content to stream in a form of XML document
```

How do I use the call with the stream as the parameter to get the XML as a string?

I have researched and tried several things and just still can't get it..

Comment: Do you think it would be OK if you posted the full signature of the `ExportToXML` methods?

Comment: Public Sub ExportToXML(stream As System.IO.Stream)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a MemoryStream as the stream to export the XML to, and then read the MemoryStream back with a StreamReader:

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xmlData As String = ""
        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            ExportToXML(ms)
            ms.Position = 0
            Using sr As New StreamReader(ms)
                xmlData = sr.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(xmlData)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    ' a dummy method for testing
    Private Sub ExportToXML(ms As MemoryStream)
        Dim bytes = Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!")
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.length)
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Added:** Alternatively, as [suggested by Coderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234262/1115360):

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream
    ExportToXML(ms)
    xmlData = Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
End Using
```

A small effort at testing did not show any discernible efficiency difference.

Comment: Could I read it straight into a StreamReader called sr and then do xml=sr.ReadToEnd()?  Like, APublicProperty.ExportToXML(sr.BaseStream)...  I'm new to working with streams so...

Comment: @Chris: No, you have to write to a Stream (or something that inherits Stream - like MemoryStream). StreamReader is **not** a Stream, it is a class that you use for reading from a stream.

Comment: @Chris I've put in an alternative way of getting the memorystream into a string from someone else's suggestion. I think that code is as short as it can be, given that ExportToXML is not a function.