# How to show binary data in webbrowser control in win forms using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my database i have a field whose datatype is BLOB.I use this field to store HTML formatted text (i.e texts enclosed in html tags etc). I want to fetch this binary data and render the contents in a WebBrowser control of C# windows form. I am using the code below but its just showing 'System.Byte[]' in the webbrowser control.

```
            if(rdr9e.Read())
            {
                byte[] byt = (byte[])rdr9e["q_r_desc"];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(byt, 0, byt.Length);
                ms.Position = 0;
                webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
            }
```

Here 'q_r_desc' is the field containing binary data.My question is how do i show binary data using webbrowser control.Any help with code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the encoding of the text?

Comment: Encoding of the text is Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `byte[]` to `MemorySteam` and then assign it to [`DocumentStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your web browser control:

```
//Suppose you have an byte[] array that you load from somewhere, for exmple:
var array = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(@"<html><head></head><body>Hi dude!</body></html>");
this.webBrowser1.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(array);
```

[image]

Comment: Reza thanks for the prompt reply once again. I tried your above code it works in a way, but the text its rendering is not what i had saved in the database. I mean to say that the characters being rendered are in some foreign language

Comment: Well let me explain my requirement . I have a fully working web application   made using PHP5 and MySql. In the website i have a WYSIWYG editor.Through this editor i save HTML text i.e. formatted text containing text and some image etc. into Blob field. Now i am necessitated to create an windows application which will MOMENTARILY connect to  remote server and download those formatted HTML data and display them in WebBrowser control.

Comment: Reza suppose if you are required to design such an application then what would be your approach?

Comment: So it seems, mistakenly your data in database is stores as this string `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98778/discussion-between-user1448677-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your memorystream using a streamreader and the write out the results into a string / output...

[How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream)

Comment: good news friends, i have solved the above problem.The cause of the problem was that i have not been saving/inserting the data into blob field in a correct way