# C# Parse HTML Post Data

Tags: c#, parsing, character-encoding

I have MemoryStream data (HTML POST Data) which i need to parse it.
Converting it to string give result like below

```
key1=value+1&key2=val++2
```

Now the problem is that all this + are space in html. Am not sure why space is converting to +

This is how i am converting MemoryStream to string

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request.PostData.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, your data needs to be url encoded.

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`:

```cs
using System.Web;
var data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.PostData);
```

See more in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode).

You can also use JSON format for POST.

Comment: Hello, i am using **MiniHttpd** lib. request.PostData is MemoryStream and not string. And Content-Type i am getting is **text/plain;charset=UTF-8**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the data you are retrieving are encoded with URL rules.
You can discover why data are encoded to this format reading [this simple article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) from W3c school.

To encode/decode your post **string** you may use this couple of methods:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString); // Encode
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(yourString); // Decode
```

You can find more informations about URL manipulation functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=netframework-4.5.1).

**Note:** If you need to encode/decode an array of string you need to enumerate your collection with a for or foreach statement. Remember that with this kind of cycles you cannot directly change the cycle variable value during the enumeration (so probably you need a temporary storage variable).

At least, to efficiently parse strings, I suggest you to use the `System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex` class and learn the regex "language".
 
You can find some example on how to use Regex [here](https://regex101.com/); Regex101 site has also a C# code generator that shows you how to translate your regex into code.

Comment: Hello, i am using MiniHttpd lib. request.PostData is MemoryStream and not string. And Content-Type i am getting is text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Comment: You can convert the memorystream object to a common string. Watch this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream

Comment: Or you can simply read the stream:

    string postDataString = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.PostData))
        postDataString  = reader.ReadToEnd();